# how get next autonumber from one column jdbc database?

Tags: java

I am using an access mdb file as my database . Inside the table in my database I use id as autonumber. Now. I wanted to know how can i get the next generated auto number field in access database to put in java JTextField!

Comment: Means what u want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get next number you can insert a "blank" row and use the number that was generated for it.

If your insert statement is stmt:

```
int nextKey = 0;
ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (keys.next())
{
    nextKey = keys.getInt(1);
}
```

[See statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys())

Alternatively you could generate new id number with

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM yourTable
```

though this doesn't guarantee that the number will stay unused (by some other query) before you do anything with it.